# Junit test: Test multiple Exception

Tags: java, exception, junit

For my application I want to check a function which throws two `Exceptions`. I want to check these `Exceptions` by JUnit.

Here an example:

```
class MyFoo {
    public void doSomeStuff(ArrayList<Object> objectList) {
        if (objectList.size() >= 2) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("");
        }
        if (objectList.size() == 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("");
        } else {
            //do further Stuff
        }
    }
}
```

So now i want to check this function. I know how to test a single exception, but is there a way to check both exception at once? Or is it better to check every exception in a own test?

Here the test for one exception:

```
public class MyFooTest {

    @Rule
    public ExpectedException thrown=  ExpectedException.none();


    @Test
    public void testDoSomeStuff() {
       thrown.expect(IllegalArgumentException.class);
       List<Object> objectList=new ArrayList<>();
       objectList.add(new Object());
       objectList.add(new Object());
       objectList.add(new Object());
       doSomeStuff(objectList);
    }
}
```

May be I am totally wrong to check both exception at once. So introduce me.

Comment: Both exceptions won't be thrown never.  You have to write two test cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would assert that the correct exception is thrown in two different test cases.

```
@Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
public void shouldThrowExceptionWhenListIsEmpty() {
    doSomeStuff(Collections.emptyList());
}

@Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
public void shouldThrowExceptionWhenListIsBiggerThanTwo() {
    doSomeStuff(Arrays.asList(new Object(), new Object(), new Object()));
}
```

If one constraint change, you only change one test. The other one remains unchanged.

Answer (score 2):

I would *highly recommend* single-path scenarios per method for sanity purposes (if you have 17 exceptions in a single test and that test fails, you get to check all 17 of those possibilities) but you also asked if it was possible. Sure it is, you can use assert.fail with try/catches if you want to stuff everything together, where an expected exception skips over the Fail statement.

```
@Test
public void testDoSomeStuff() {
    List<Object> objectList=new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        doSomeStuff(objectList);
        Assert.fail("Should throw IllegalArgumentException!"):
    }
    catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
        logger.info("Threw IllegalArgumentException as expected.");
    }

    objectList.add(new Object());
    objectList.add(new Object());
    objectList.add(new Object());

    try {
        doSomeStuff(objectList);
        Assert.fail("Should throw IllegalArgumentException!"):
    }
    catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
        logger.info("Threw IllegalArgumentException as expected.");
    }
}
```

Comment: This approach is much more sane; really when you're working with something like Mockito to progressively build out validation like OP.

Answer (score 1):

You should create two tests for specific situations. In this case one for each exception will keep the unit tests clean and clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can have two test methods and have the expectation for each type of exception on them. In your case, I think your logic needs only one exception because you can collapse your conditions: `if (objectList.isEmpty() || (objectList.size() >= 2))`...then check for `IllegalArgumentException` with different samples.

On the other hand, if you really want to have that separated, have two methods with two expectations: `@Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)`.

```
@Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
public void doSomeStuff1() {
  doSomeStuff(Collections.emptyList());
}

@Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
public void doSomeStuff2() {
  List<Object> sample = new ArrayList<Object>();

  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { // Change `5` for something else if you want
    sample.add(new Object());
  }
  doSomeStuff(sample);
}
```